# Unity Listener/Event like OnValueChanged for GameObject properties

Tags: c#, events, unity-game-engine

I want to call a function each time my gameObject.renderer.isVisible is set to false without using `Update(){ 
    if(gameObject.renderer.isVisible == false)
        FunctionToCall(); 
}`
It's quite ugly.

So I was wondering how can I make a Listener/Event like OnValueChanged(bool ) for GameObject properties and scripts variables in general ?
Maybe there is an easier way, I'm new to Unity so maybe I'm missing something.

Thanks and sorry for my poor english

Comment: it's simply OnBecameInvisible() as the answer states at the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [MonoBehaviour.OnBecameInvisible()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameInvisible.html).

or

```
public delegate void OnBooleanChanged(bool state);
public event OnBooleanChanged OnVisibilityChangedEvent;
private bool _isVisible;

void Start()
{
    _isVisible = renderer.isVisible;
    OnVisibilityChangedEvent += OnVisibilityChanged;
}

void Update()
{
    if((_isVisible && !renderer.isVisible) | (!_isVisible && renderer.isVisible))
    {
        _isVisible = !_isVisible;

        // example of custom function call
        OnVisibilityChanged(_isVisible); 

        // example of event call
        if(OnVisibilityChangedEvent != null) OnVisibilityChangedEvent(_isVisible); 
    }
}

private void OnVisibilityChanged(bool isVisible)
{
    // ...
}
```

or using MonoBehaviourEvents

```
void OnBecameVisible()
{
    if(OnVisibilityChangedEvent != null)
        OnVisibilityChangedEvent(true);
}

void OnBecameInvisible()
{
    if(OnVisibilityChangedEvent != null)
        OnVisibilityChangedEvent(false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I still interested by making OnValueChanged like event for script variables, any ideas ?.

Comment: Edited my answer. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your time but not really :).  I was looking to use event system to avoid Update(). Using something like renderer.isVisible.AddListener.OnValueChanged( myfunction() ) but i can't cause OnValueChanged is only for UI element. Not sure if i'm clear :s

Comment: Something like this? http://pastebin.com/VveMh08d I dont see any other ways. And I dont understand why you can't use methods that i described.

Comment: Just wanted to know how to make it work with event for other issues (MonoBehavior script variables), the gameObject.renderer.isVisible was a particular issue. Thanks a lot !